# How to find domain names which start with “karath”?

Tags: search-engine, domain-name

I know the first 6 characters of a domain name. I also know that the domain is about palmistry!

I need a search engine that can search all valid domain names that starts with "karath", so it should search all valid domain names on the web with search expression of "karath*"

I is better that it shoes some description about each domain.

Is there any such search engine?

If this question is not related to this community (off-topic) please tell me which community is related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the complete list of all registered domains from whoisxmlapi at:

https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-database-download.php

Please note that it’s a paid service, but you do not have any other option. After download the list, you can apply your desired logic (search if domain contain the string“karath”).

Keep in mind that this list is updating every day, so then you can only scan all the daily registered domains from here (free service):

https://whoisds.com/newly-registered-domains

And keep track only the delta’s.